# How to create bigger parentheses in a math term with a line break

Tags: equations

I know, this is a big ass formula and therefore not very graphic. I hope it is still possible to see the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Re}\left\{(A_1(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_1-f_2}{2} t + \Phi_1(t)} + A_2(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_2-f_1}{2} t + \Phi_2(t)})\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_1+f_2}{2}}\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I want the small brackets `()` starting just before A_1(t) and ending after Phi_2(t)}) to be as big as the fancy brackets `{}` which are encapsulating the whole term. I have tried with `\left\(` and `\right\)`, but it doesn't work. I have read it doesn't work, because the math term is more than one line long. Just I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: You can try to approximate the size using `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and so on.

Comment: well, i'm on my laptop, which doesn't have tex installed, so i can't experiment, but i don't see a line break, nor do i see any reason why `\left(` and `\right) shouldn't work.  if you really do have to apply extreme measures, then `\vphantom` should help if you're beyond the range of the `\Big...` commands.

Comment: no TeX here either, but iirc you can add ``\right.`` and ``\left.`` (with a dot!) to match the missing closing or opening brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Text before.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \operatorname{Re}\Bigl\{
            &\Bigl(A_1(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_1-f_2}{2} t + \Phi_1(t)} \\
            &\quad+ A_2(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_2-f_1}{2} t +
            \Phi_2(t)}\Bigr)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_1+f_2}{2}}
        \Bigr\}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Text after.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Thx Gustavo! Just, why doesn't \left\ and \right\ work? I just realized I have used it for the fancy brackets, so why wouldn't it work for the normal ones? I have tried this: `\operatorname{Re}\left\{\left\(A_1(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_1-f_2}{2} t + \Phi_1(t)} + A_2(t)\,\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_2-f_1}{2} t + \Phi_2(t)}\right\)\mathrm{e}^{j 2\pi \frac{f_1+f_2}{2}}\right\}\notag`and it gives plenty errors. Probably I should have mentioned, I am using this equation line in an align-environment.

Comment: A `+` has become `=`. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Oops, a typo.  Thanks for spotting it: I’ll correct it shortly.

Comment: @Luk: `\left` and `\right` will work for the round parentheses too, but you need to specify them *without* the backslash: it is `\left( ... \right)`, *not* `\left\( ... \right\)`.  But in the title of your question you were speaking of  splitting the formula over two lines…

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you use `\exp(...)` notation instead of `e^{...}` notation: The more material is rendered at text rather than at script or scriptscript size, the better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\Re\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
\Re\Bigl\{\Bigl[&A_1(t)\exp \bigl(j 2\pi \tfrac{1}{2}(f_1-f_2) t + \Phi_1(t)\bigr) \\
+ &A_2(t)\exp\bigl(j 2\pi \tfrac{1}{2}(f_2-f_1) t + \Phi_2(t)\bigr)\Bigr]\exp\bigl(j 2\pi \tfrac{1}{2}(f_1+f_2)\bigr)\Bigr\}
\end{split}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```